# what is hyperledger-fabric chainfile? and where can I get it?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

I had brought up the hyperledger-fabric network with its official document by executing `./byfn.sh -m up`.

Official document site :http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/build_network.html

The script had automatically made a transaction with a and b.

The specific command was `peer chaincode invoke -o orderer.example.com:7050 --tls true --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem -C mychannel -n mycc -c '{"Args":["invoke","a","b","10"]}'`.

Now, I want to get the chainfile that contains transaction record. But I do not know where it is.

OS: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

fabric version:release-1.1

Answer (score 0):

The `chaincode` package is installed on the peer is the serialized bytes of a protobuf message. The protobuf in a `ChainDeploymentSpec` message, which is defined in the proto file at "https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release-1.1/protos/peer/chaincode.proto"

The `chaincode` source files are stored in a serialized archive file stored in the `code_package` field of the `ChainDeploymentSpec`.